React - Prevent child re-render when browser resize
I have a react app with a scenario where a parent component with 3 different layouts where the child components are rendered. The layout (3 fragments (default) or 2 fragments or 1 fragment) is decided by the browser window size (width)
The issue is, the child component are re-rendered whenever browser window is resized.
Below is the structure of the parent component,
const Parent = (props) => {

let columns = [
    <Fragment key={1}>
      <CustomerInfo {...customerProps} />
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key={2}>
      <ContactInformation {...contactProps} />
      <PaymentOption  {...paymentProps} />
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key={3}>
      <AddressInfo {...addressProps} />,
    </Fragment>,
  ];

  if (isTwoColumnLayout) {
    columns = [
      <Fragment key={1}>
         <CustomerInfo {...customerProps} />
         <ContactInformation {...contactProps} />
         <PaymentOption  {...paymentProps} />
      </Fragment>,
      <Fragment key={2}>
         <AddressInfo {...addressProps} />,
      </Fragment>,
    ];
  } else if (isOneColumnLayout) {
    columns = [
      <Fragment key={1}>
        <CustomerInfo {...customerProps} />
         <ContactInformation {...contactProps} />
         <PaymentOption  {...paymentProps} />
         <AddressInfo {...addressProps} />,
      </Fragment>,
    ];
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FlexColumns columns={columns} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

I would like the app not to re-render the child component, when browser window size is changed. Specifically I would like the child component (<PaymentOption  {...paymentProps} />) not to re-render.
Appreciate your help,
Thanks.
I tried to make use of React's useMemo hook in the parent component, but that didn't solve my issue
**const PaymentOptionMemo = useMemo(() => {
  return <PaymentOption {...paymentProps} />
  }, []);**

....

let columns = [
    <Fragment key={1}>
      <CustomerInfo {...customerProps} />
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key={2}>
      <ContactInformation {...contactProps} />
**      <Fragment children={PaymentOptionMemo} />**
    </Fragment>,
    <Fragment key={3}>
      <AddressInfo {...addressProps} />,
    </Fragment>,
  ];

...


If the child components' render logic is tied closely to the parent’s layout logic, consider separating these concerns. This way, the child components are not dependent on layout changes.
const Parent = (props) => {
  const childComponents = useMemo(() => (
    <>
      <CustomerInfo {...customerProps} />
      <ContactInformation {...contactProps} />
      <PaymentOption {...paymentProps} />
      <AddressInfo {...addressProps} />
    </>
  ), [customerProps, contactProps, paymentProps, addressProps]);

  let columns;
  if (isTwoColumnLayout) {
    columns = [/* arrange columns based on childComponents */];
  } else if (isOneColumnLayout) {
    columns = [/* arrange columns based on childComponents */];
  } else {
    columns = [/* arrange columns based on childComponents */];
  }

  return <FlexColumns columns={columns} />;
};

Ensure that the key properties are not causing the component to unmount and remount. If the key changes, React will treat it as a different component, causing a re-render.
// Avoid changing keys unnecessarily
<Fragment key="fixed-key">
  <PaymentOption {...paymentProps} />
</Fragment>

If your child component receives functions as props, wrap them with useCallback to avoid passing new function references on each render.
const handlePaymentChange = useCallback((newPayment) => {
  // handle change
}, []);

const paymentProps = {
  ...otherProps,
  onChange: handlePaymentChange
};
``

